# Swiftのタイプオブジェクトから、動的にイニシャライザを呼ぶ方法

Tags: ios, swift

Swiftの列挙型がCountを返してくれないので、グローバル関数でループを回して数えるようなことを考えています。

```
protocol CountableIntEnum {
    init?(rawValue: Int)
}

func enumCount(CountableEnumType: CountableIntEnum.Type) -> Int {
    var count = 0
    while CountableEnumType(rawValue: count) != nil {
        count++
    }
    return count
}

enum Podium: Int, CountableIntEnum {
    case First = 0
    case Second
    case Third

    static let count = enumCount(Podium)
}

println(Podium.count)
```

上記のようなコードを記述すると、コーディング中は問題ないのですが
ビルド時に

```
Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11
While emitting IR SIL function @_TF8EnumTest9enumCountFPMPS_16CountableIntEnum_Si for 'enumCount'
```

というエラーでビルドすることが出来ません。

クラスオブジェクトを変数に入れて、そのイニシャライザを呼ぶ正しい方法はどのようにすればよいでしょうか？

また、別の方法でもいいのですが、Foundationの力を借りずに動的にEnumType(rawValue: Int)を呼ぶ方法などはないでしょうか？

Answer (score 4, accepted):

関数の定義を以下のように変更すれば動作するようです。

```
func enumCount<T:CountableIntEnum>(CountableEnumType: T.Type) -> Int
```

Comment: 本当ですね。ありがとうございます。
ちなみに
    
    func enumCount(CountableEnumType: Podium.Type) -> Int
    
でも動いたので、おそらく実装の伴わないプロトコルだと静的に処理できなくてコンパイル出来ない感じでしょうかね、、、
でもって、ジェネリクスを使った場合だと、抽象的に解釈して通過してくれる感じですかね